# Creating pointers so segmentation faults do not occur and printing the values of the pointers with printf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I am trying to print the values of pointers but am getting a segmentation fault error. I know that a segmentation fault occurs when I try to use memory locations that I shouldn't have access to, but I don't know how to avoid getting the error in this program, or how to create pointers so that a segmentation fault does not occur in general.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funct(int *p2)
{
     p2 = (int *)malloc(4);
     *p2 = 14;
     printf("%d\n", *p2);
}

int main()
{
     int *p;
     funct(p);
     printf("%d\n",*p);

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the *value* of the variable `p` to the function `funct`.  Nothing that happens in the function will have any effect on it, so when you call `printf` on the next line you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.  This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which manifests as a segfault.

You need to pass the address of `p` to the function, and change the type of the parameter to match.

> I am trying to print the values of pointers but am getting a segmentation fault error. I know that a segmentation fault occurs when I try to use memory locations that I shouldn't have access to, but I don't know how to avoid getting the error in this program, or how to create pointers so that a segmentation fault does not occur in general.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funct(int **p2)
{
     *p2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
     **p2 = 14;
     printf("%d\n", **p2);
}

int main()
{
     int *p;
     funct(&p);
     printf("%d\n",*p);

     return 0;
}
```